# Closing the bottom of a sphere with a plane

Tags: blender

I would like to close the bottom of my shape with a plane, how do I go about doing that? And is it possible to smoothen out the edges connecting the plane and my object too?

[Top View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB15n.jpg)

[Bottom View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPC2o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a point in the middle of the plane geometry and close it with triangles or rectangles (based on your standard shape). Please refer to this answer which explains the solution to a similar situation: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/how-to-fill-a-hole-in-face